# Problem when building Python-3.7.3 from source on Mac M1

Tags: python

I have to install Python 3.7.3 on my Mac M1.

I downloaded Python, moved into the folder and executed the following command:

`./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ --prefix=path_to_install`
(I replaced `path_to_install` with a real path)

This is the output that I receive:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking for python3.7... python3.7
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for g++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
```

When I explicitly set the CXX env variable like so:

`CXX=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/g++ ./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ --prefix=/Users/fryderykkogl/python_for_imfusion`

or

`CXX=/usr/bin/g++ ./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ --prefix=/Users/fryderykkogl/python_for_imfusion`

I get the following error:

```
hecking build system type... arm-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking for python3.7... python3.7
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
```

running `g++ --version` returns this:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and running `which g++` returns

```
/usr/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Homebrew package manager (https://brew.sh/)?

Then you can install a specific version with `brew install python@3.7.3`

UPDATE: It looks like in recent versions of clang, a breaking change was made for the python build scripts: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2143.  A fix is present in version 3.7.13: https://docs.python.org/release/3.7.13/whatsnew/changelog.html#changelog

> bpo-45405: Prevent internal configure error when running configure
> with recent versions of clang. Patch by David Bohman

Try giving that version a shot

Comment: I need to use this Python version in conjunction with another piece of software and in the instructions it explicitly says "not compatible with neither the python version from Apple nor the one from brew. Instead you need to build python yourself"

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Well it looks like it can't find the g++ compiler and you can specify it with CXX environment variable like `CXX=... ./configure --enable-shared --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ `.  Do you have XCode/command line tools installed? That usually installs g++ I believe. 

If you run `g++ --version` on the command line is anything found?

Comment: I have the command line tools and g++ installed. When I specified it as suggested, the error starts earlier, the line ```checking for g++... no``` doesn't get printed anymore

Comment: oo, what's the error in that case? and what does `g++ --version` give?

Comment: I updated the original question to include this info

Comment: It looks like there was a breaking change in recent version of clang for python build scripts according to this thread: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2143  It looks like python version 3.7.8+ received a fix, would that version work for program you're trying to run?

Comment: I think it should work, but the same error appears when I try it with e.g. 3.7.9 and 3.8.12

Comment: hmm, try 3.7.13? according to https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2306#issuecomment-1085525048

Comment: that worked, thanks! but now in the next step I run ```make -j 8``` and I get the following output (it's really long, so here's a [link](https://justpaste.it/9cw7d))